# Strange behavior of constraints, iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have two root views on superview.

[image]

All views and constraints I've added from code. Top view have H:|-0-[view]-0-|. Same vfl code have bottom view. Next, top view attached top to top, bottom to top of second view, second bottom attached to bottom. The code is V:|-0-[topView]-0-[secondView]-0-|.

Second view have intrinsic height, so height of both views depends on this value. When I change bottom view height and animate layoutIfNeed all works fine for me.
Next, bottom view have some subviews. Bottom is simple view-container and top is button. Both of them attached to left / right, like H:|-0-[view]-0-|. Bottom view has intrinsic height too, so vertically them attached like outside views, without (!) attaching button to top of superview (V:[button]-0-[secondView]-0-|). Second view is ATTACHED bottom to bottom, but when I animating changing height of this container, its subviews go top on iOS 8.

[image: fine]
[image: bad]

View hierarchy is

[image: hierarchy]

Constraints:

```
H:|-0-[topView]-0-|
H:|-0-[bottomView]-0-|
V:|-0-[topView]-0-[bottomView(110)]-0-|

H:|-0-[buttonBackCamera]-0-|
H:|-0-[grayView]-0-|
V:[buttonBackCamera]-0-[grayView(85)]-0-| //here is constraint, that MUST attach grayView to bottom.
```

While debugging, I noticed, that constraint is attached, active and it must work, but :( .

Any thoughts about this?

UPDATE

I've checked this on iOS 8.3, all works fine too.

Comment: What is `secondView` in your comments? Is that the bottom view in your diagram? And are the buttons subviews of secondView / bottom view, or are they at the same level? Do you see any constraint warnings in the console?

Comment: View hierarchy is something like this http://monosnap.com/image/kxXIv3pPlmhWLWcIrCsPIBeFIPuVmw

Comment: No any warnings in console

Comment: You should probably update your question with that hierarchy and mention the constraints you have there, it's a bit hard to follow at the moment

Comment: Did you set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`? Otherwise the autoresizing mask will create additional constraints. Are you animating the height using `frame` or by changing the `constraint` on a `constant`?

Comment: Yea, sure.
code for animating

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    self.heightConstraint.constant = sender.selected ? self.captureViewPlaceholder.width : 110;


    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.3 animations: ^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];

Comment: What view contains the `heightConstraint`? Are you sure the height is not set by something else? If you are trying to set the height of a controller's view, note that controllers set their frames from autoresizing not from autolayout.

Comment: NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: bottomView  attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual  toItem: nil attribute: nil multiplier: 1 constant: height];

yes, sure. The thing is, all works fine on iOS 7

Answer (score 0):

Make sure bottom view contains constraint from Leading to superview, Trailing to Superview and Bottom to Bottom Guide.
And if you are still facing any issue then go for,

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
  [self.view layoutIfneeded];
}
```

Comment: I've checked this already. I've tried to layout superview and bottom subview. Bottom subview didn't layout after layoutIfNeeded, so I tried to use layoutSubviews. No result anyway.
Bottom subView attached to it's superview bottom, it's not attached to bottom guide

Comment: do you have provided any top constraint..?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you please rephrase? Are you talking about what level, of what view?

Comment: can you share screenshot of constraint.

Comment: I'm using vfl. No IB.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I got the problem entirely but may I suggest you to check the size class that is selected and the size class for each of the enabled constraint.
[image]

Comment: Size classes are disabled. All constraints are added from code.